# svn tortoisesvn redirect cycle detected for URL

Tags: apache, svn

i know duplicate questions about my topic.
but other answer is not helping me.

below is my conf file(i show only changed conf compared to the default conf)

httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    #Require all denied (default)
    Require all granted (change)
</Directory>
```

10-subversion.conf

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
LoadModule dontdothat_module  modules/mod_dontdothat.so

Alias /test /home/svn/test
<Location /test>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /home/svn/test
SVNListParentPath On
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SVN Repository"
</Location>
```

In test folder, it has repositry like repo1, repo2.

Below all works well in web browser.

http://127.0.0.1/test

http://127.0.0.1/test/repo1

http://127.0.0.1/test/repo1/trunk

http://127.0.0.1/test/repo1/tags

But in tortoise work not one link below:

http://127.0.0.1/test/repo1

this link show error below:

redirect cycel detected for URL 'http://127.0.0.1/test/repo1'

other link(/test, /test/repo1/tags, /test/repo2/trunk) works well.

how can i solve this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AuthType Basic

->

AuthType None

I solved it..